# Performing a select statement row by row, implementing a while or do loop

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I am sorta new to SQL server, coming from SAS, so I apologize if this is an easy question.

I am trying to select each row from a table
ex.
select * from A

but I want to do that and change what the select statement has in the last row of table A (so when the last row of A is selected, I want to have a slightly different select statement)

I am not sure how to go about implementing an if statement for this...any ideas?

I know how to select the top or last row, ut the goal would be

if (notlastrow) do this:
select statement
if lastrow do this:
different select statement
end;

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What is the end result and what might it look like?

Comment: Unless you do an order by, the last row may differ with each query - are you sure you want to do this? What is special about the last row?

Comment: Well my select statement in this case is outputting variables into text and outputs sections for each row, and the last section needs to have some things different to work in this context...I guess an wasy way to explain it is it is outputting A,B,C,D,E,F through Z and there wont be a comma after Z, so my select statement for the last row would exclude the comma